# google chrome doesn't open ip:8080 but on IE works

Tags: apache, docker

I've installed docker and i've created container with port expose 8080:80 and tried to connect via browser to web server and I've noticed something strange, on IE the connection is working like a charm towards web server but on Chrome doesn't work, why is that?

[image]

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED              STATUS              PORTS                  NAMES
46a1e9019c36        ubuntu:latest       "/bin/bash"         About a minute ago   Up About a minute   0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp   apache_server_1
```

**From other servers I can connect to webserver via port 8080.**

```
wget 10.xxx.xx.144:8080
--2018-06-04 22:49:16--  http://10.xxx.xx.144:8080/
Connecting to 10.xxx.xx.144:8080... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 10918 (11K) [text/html]
Saving to: `index.html'

100%[==============================================================================================================================>] 10,918      --.-K/s   in 0s

2018-06-04 22:49:16 (521 MB/s) - `index.html' saved [10918/10918]
```

Comment: Your ip address is totally visible in the error message on chrome. Maybe adding http:// in the chrome would help?

Comment: Run the docker container on different port, chrome cookie may be saved your port with th same IP for different application.

Answer (score 0):

Try clear the browser history in chrome and access . Check for any proxy configuration between IE and chrome

Comment: I did that, nothing happend.